# Encapsulation vs Inheritence

Tags: inheritance, encapsulation

My language is c++ but I feel the answer should be general

I can choose between two option for my class, B:

1) Have B inherit from A, and make some of the methods of A virtual

2) Declare an instance of A within B.

This question is about what is optimal in terms of run time, as both will work fine.

What I think is option 1 is less optimal for instances of both A and B because there is a layer of indirection at run time as the correct function is choosen from the V table.

Is this correct?

Comment: unless you have a VERY good reason to, it is better to worry about readability and maintainability than to worry about how many times you dereference a pointer

Comment: "Which is optimal" almost always comes down to compiler/platform dependent issues. Use a profiler, measure the differences.

Comment: Joshua Block devotes an entire item in his book Effective Java, 2nd Ed. to "Favor composition over inheritance".  The reasons are compelling.  This would suggest that you favor approach 2.  The reasons to favor approach 1 would be if B really is an A -and- A has been designed and properly documented for inheritance.  Under most circumstances, the performance differences attributed solely to inheritance versus composition (including method forwarding) will be trivial ... meaning you should choose the design that makes the most sense (as above).

Answer (score 3):

Unless your code is performance-critical, you should not worry about the difference in run-time indirection. You should use the option that makes sense within the context of your application.

For Option 1, B *is* an A.

For Option 2, B *has* an A.

If the code is performance-critical, you should implement and test both versions, as mentioned by Almo.

Comment: Slightly unrelated, but what is meant by "performance-critical"? Isn't it a common goal to have you program running as fast as possible? I understand avoiding premature optimization, but what's an example of an application that would be "performance-critical"?

Comment: That's a good question. Speed is often desired, but is not really needed. As long as the program is fast enough, it is much more important that it is actually correct. In order to ensure it is correct, it must be easy for the programmer(s) to understand the code.

Comment: Performance-critical applications would be where there is a risk of not being "fast enough". Think scientific analyses or simulations that take a long time and a firm project schedule, a video game graphics engine that needs to run smoothly to be accepted by players, or a control system that needs to run in real time on limited hardware. A basic data-entry application would not be performance-critical, as there is little risk that the computer can keep up with a typist.

Comment: Oh, good point; I didn't even think of a game engine. That makes sense.